# How to populate database in RoR from a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, open-uri

I want to store json data which is stored at some url. How can that be done?

Comment: use gem like `httparty` or `faraday` to communicate with the url and get the data from it in json format then parse the data received in the `http response` and store it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment above, I would recommend a gem like `httparty`. You can send a get request to the desired url, like `response =   HTTParty.get('www.exampleurl.com')` and use the rails json parsing gem/feature to parse it and create a record from that. But to sum things up:

```
include 'httparty'

response =   HTTParty.get('www.exampleurl.com')
json_response = JSON.parse(response)

json_response.each do |json|
   Object.create(name: json.name, some_field: json.some_field)
end
```